# How can I import airflow custom operators, plugins without error in IDE

Tags: python, airflow

I'm not an expert python developer that's why I'll just ***outline my steps***.

## SETUP PART

I created a directory **~/Desktop/airflow** for apache-airflow and made

> export AIRFLOW_HOME=**~/Desktop/airflow**

then I created **venv** using

> python3 -m venv ~/Desktop/airflow

the result is

[image]

then I made

> source bin/activate
>
> pip3 install apache-airflow==1.10.9
>
> airflow initdb

the result is

[image]

In my **airflow.cfg** file I checked dags and plugins directories. I created dags and plugins directories inside **$AIRFLOW_HOME/Desktop/airflow**

I started **airflow webserver** and **scheduler** and made sure that everything works fine.

## CUSTOM PLUGIN PART

I found a lot of ways how we can create airflow plugins. I tried all the possible ways. Let's start.

First one is to create a plugin folder inside (**first_plugin**) a project and then create a python file (**first_operator.py**)

```
import logging

from airflow.operators import BaseOperator
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class FirstOperator(BaseOperator):

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FirstOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def execute(self, context):
        log.info("Hello World!")


class FirstOperatorPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "first_plugin"
    operators = [FirstOperator]
```

it looks like

[image]

then I just move my plugin folder (**first_plugin**) to **$AIRFLOW_HOME/DESKTOP/airflow/plugins** and restart airflow webserver and scheduler.

Now time to create a custom dag with using my custom operator. How to import your plugin correct is a challenge. There are a lot of possible ways to import custom operators. I'll show what I tried.

1. **from airflow.operators import FirstOperator** - *deprecated*
2. from airflow.operators.**first_plugin** import FirstOperator
3. from airflow.operators.**first_operator** import FirstOperator
4. from first_plugin.first_operator import FirstOperator

None of these ways helped me during importing in Pycharm IDE. For example,

> from airflow.operators.**first_plugin** import FirstOperator

[image]

But I'm sure if I ignore the import line and put my custom dag into dags folder it'll work fine. (I tried). Moreover, I decided to check airflow logs (in DEBUG mode).

What logs I see when I restart airflow webserver

[image]

I spent 2 days and I still have no any solution. Probably you guys tell me to try other ways. I tried.

https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-importing-custom-hooks-operators/https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-importing-custom-hooks-operators/

https://pybit.es/introduction-airflow.html

All of them are working ways but none of them solves my IDE importing problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have bypassed the plugins step and did it in a pure python-ish way. It seems that is also what docs say for the latest version (1.10.12).

This is my folder structure:

```
AIRFLOW_HOME
├── dags
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── my_dag.py
└── utils
    ├── __init__.py
    └── custom_operator.py
```

Make sure that `PYTHONPATH` contains `AIRFLOW_HOME` path. And then you can import it like this:

```
from custom_operator.hello_operator import HelloOperator
```

Read more here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/custom-operator.html#creating-a-custom-operator

Answer (score 0):

We do not need to create a folder `plugin` and add `custom operators`. With Airflow 2.0+, we only need to create a folder inside our project and import it inside dag files.

```
airflow_project
+--custom_operator
   +--first_operator.py
+--dags
   +--dag_1.py
```

Inside dag_1.py, you can import custom operators/hooks as:

```
from custom_operator.first_operator import FirstOperator
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the folder structure that worked for me, make sure the custom operators are inside an `operators` folder, same for `sensors` and `hooks`. The **init**.py files should be empty.

```
plugins
├── __init__.py
├── operators
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── glue_crawler_operator.py
│   └── gsheet_to_redshift_operator.py
└── sensors
    ├── __init__.py
    └── glue_crawler_sensor.py
```

Also check that `plugins_folder` in the `airflow.cfg` file points to your plugins folder.

For example, to import the gsheet_to_redshift_operator operator without errors I used the following statement:

`from operators.gsheet_to_redshift_operator import GsheetToRSOperator`